# Fixing Mismatched Image Class in Existing Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image

After migrating my wordpress site, I found out that the image class of some of my images in the existing posts are mismatched. However, I am not able to figure out any automated method to fix the issue.

As we all know, when an image is inserted in a post, wordpress would assign an image class and generate some markups automatically like this:

```
<img class=" size-full wp-image-YYYYY aligncenter" src="https://......XXXXX.jpg">
```

which the YYYYY in the “wp-image-” code is exactly the ID of the image.

However, in my site, probably due to some errors occurred during migration, the image ID of some of my images are off by a bit. For example, the original image ID 10000 is now 10002 in my new site. However, in the post content, the markup of the image is still `wp-image-10000`. This creates a problem that the image class associated is mismatched from the correct image id, and the images are such not responsive.

The obvious fix of this problem is to update the `wp-image-YYYYY` code to the correct image ID in the posts (i.e. changing `wp-image-10000` to `wp-image-10002`). Or else, I could just reinsert the image into the post and wordpress would reassign a correct image class accordingly. However, given that I have hundreds of existing posts and thousands of existing images, it is not possible for me to check if the image class of each image is correct manually.

While I don't know anything about coding, I have tried to run the code in the below website, and tried to twist the code from `if ( !$has_class )`  to `if ( $has_class )` to fit my scenario, which it does not work at all:
https://letswp.io/add-attachment-id-to-the-class-of-wordpress-images/

I would be very grateful if someone could provide an automated solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the code mentioned in the link, you can make more tweaks that my fix your issue, since you do not need to append but rather replace the class.

```
function lwp_attachment_id_class( $attr, $attachment ) {

    $class_attr = isset( $attr['class'] ) ? $attr['class'] : '';
    $has_class = preg_match(
        '/wp\-image\-[0-9]+/',
        $class_attr,
        $matches
    );

    // Check if the image is missing the class
    if ( $has_class ) {
        $new_class = sprintf( ' wp-image-%d', $attachment->ID );
        foreach($matches as $match)
            $attr['class'] = str_replace($match, $new_class, $attr['class']);
    }
    return $attr;
}

add_filter(
    'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'lwp_attachment_id_class', 10, 2
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it seems the code is not working as expected. When I inspect the element of the images after adding the code into functions.php, the class  is still wp-image-(incorrect id).

Comment: For testing purpose, I have tried to remove the image class of an image and apply the code in the original link to create image class automatically. It turns out that the original code does not work in my site either. I wonder what is going wrong.